# Is group policy management available only on Windows server 2003,2008 or 2012 only?

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, deployment, office-deployment-tool

Hi i want to know that is Is group policy management available only on Windows server 2003,2008 or 2012 only or we can do that on windows 7 or 8 also.

i want to manage software deployment on 10 machines using group policy management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off if you want to manage Group Policy (GPMC.msc I assume) you need to download RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools), install them on your workstation PC and then enable these features after you have installed RSAT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage group policy from a workstation. Install RSAT on the workstation. One of its things is group policy management. It's basically just a group policy interface to the server, not group policy itself (meaning, you won't be managing another group policy, potentially clashing, it's just an interface)